# Image storage in iOS devices, the appropriate behavior?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiimage

I'm kinda puzzeled about image storage in iOS devices for an app i'm making.

My requirement is to load an Image onto a tableViewCell, lets say in the default Image space of a UITableViewCell and hence isnt a background image.

Now The user can either add an Image either via the PhotoDirectory or take an entirely new image.

If a new image is taken, where should that image be stored preferebly? In the default photo directory ? or in the documents folder of the app sandbox?

Because these are image files, I'm afraid that store images within the app bundle can make it pretty big, I'm afraid I dont wana cross the size limit.

Performance wise though... what would be a better option?

Comment: Cross what limit? The only limit on app size that I can think of pertains to delivering your app from the App Store. Apps over a certain size can be delivered over the air, for example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have an app that also does some of the things you describe.  My solutions was to create a singleton that I call my imageStore.  You can find information about a singleton [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html)

In this imageStore, I store all my "full size" images; however, like you I am concerned about the size of these images, so instead of using them directly, I use thumbnails.  What I do is this.  For each object that I want to represent in the table, I make sure the object has a UIImage defined that is about thumnail size (64x64 or any size you desire).  Then an object is created, I create a thumbnail that I store along with the object.  I use this thumbnail instead of the larger images where I can get a way with it, like on a table cell.

I'm not behind my Mac at the moment, but if you want I can post some code later to demonstrate both the singleton and the creation and usage of the thumbnail.

Here is my header file for the ImageStore

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BPImageStore : NSObject {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
}

+ (BPImageStore *)defaultImageStore;

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)i forKey:(NSString *)s;
- (UIImage *)imageForKey:(NSString *)s;
- (void)deleteImageForKey:(NSString *)s;

@end
```

Here is the ImageStore.m file - my Singleton

```
#import "BPImageStore.h"

static BPImageStore *defaultImageStore = nil;

@implementation BPImageStore

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [[self defaultImageStore] retain];
}

+ (BPImageStore *)defaultImageStore {
    if(!defaultImageStore) {
        defaultImageStore = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return defaultImageStore;
}

- (id)init
{

    if(defaultImageStore) {
        return defaultImageStore;
    }

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(clearCach:) name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) clearCache:(NSNotification *)note {
    [dictionary removeAllObjects];
}

- (oneway void) release {
    // no op
}

- (id)retain {
    return self;
}

- (NSUInteger)retainCount {
    return NSUIntegerMax;
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)i forKey:(NSString *)s {
    [dictionary setObject:i forKey:s];

    // Create full path for image
    NSString *imagePath = pathInDocumentDirectory(s);

    // Turn image into JPEG data
    NSData *d = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(i, 0.5);

    // Write it to full path
    [d writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

}

- (UIImage *)imageForKey:(NSString *)s {
    // if possible, get it from the dictionary
    UIImage *result = [dictionary objectForKey:s];
    if(!result) {
        // Create UIImage object from file
        result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathInDocumentDirectory(s)];
        if (result)
            [dictionary setObject:result forKey:s];
    }
    return result;
}

- (void)deleteImageForKey:(NSString *)s {
    if(!s) {
        return;
    }
    [dictionary removeObjectForKey:s];
    NSString *path = pathInDocumentDirectory(s);
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
}

@end
```

Here is where I use the image store.  In my Object "player", I have a UIImage to store the thumbnail and I have an NSString to house a key that I create.  Each original image I put into the store has a key.  I store the key with my Player.  If I ever need the original image, I get by the unique key.  It is also worth noting here that I don't even store the original image at full size, I cut it down a bit already.  After all in my case, it is a picture of a player and nobody has too look so good as to have a full resolution picture :)

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *oldKey = [player imageKey];
    // did the player already have an image?
    if(oldKey) {
        // delete the old image
        [[BPImageStore defaultImageStore] deleteImageForKey:oldKey];
    }


    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // Create a CFUUID object  it knows how to create unique identifier
    CFUUIDRef newUniqueID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

    // Create a string from unique identifier
    CFStringRef newUniqueIDString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueID);

    // Use that unique ID to set our player imageKey
    [player setImageKey:(NSString *)newUniqueIDString];

    // we used Create in the functions to make objects, we need to release them
    CFRelease(newUniqueIDString);
    CFRelease(newUniqueID);

    //Scale the images down a bit
    UIImage *smallImage = [self scaleImage:image toSize:CGSizeMake(160.0,240.0)];


    // Store image in the imageStore with this key
    [[BPImageStore defaultImageStore] setImage:smallImage
                                        forKey:[player imageKey]];

    // Put that image onto the screen in our image view
    [playerView setImage:smallImage];

    [player setThumbnailDataFromImage:smallImage];
}
```

Here is an example of going back to get the original image from the imageStore:

```
// Go get image
NSString *imageKey = [player imageKey];
if (imageKey) {
    // Get image for image key from image store
    UIImage *imageToDisplay = [[BPImageStore defaultImageStore] imageForKey:imageKey];
    [playerView setImage:imageToDisplay];
} else {
    [playerView setImage:nil];
}
```

Finally, here is how I create a thumbnail from the original image:

```
- (void)setThumbnailDataFromImage:(UIImage *)image {
CGSize origImageSize = [image size];

CGRect newRect;
newRect.origin = CGPointZero;
newRect.size = [[self class] thumbnailSize]; // just give a size you want here instead

// How do we scale the image
float ratio = MAX(newRect.size.width/origImageSize.width, newRect.size.height/origImageSize.height);

// Create a bitmap image context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newRect.size);

// Round the corners
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:newRect cornerRadius:5.0];

[path addClip];

// Into what rectangle shall I composite the image
CGRect projectRect;
projectRect.size.width = ratio * origImageSize.width;
projectRect.size.height = ratio *origImageSize.height;
projectRect.origin.x = (newRect.size.width - projectRect.size.width) / 2.0;
projectRect.origin.y = (newRect.size.height - projectRect.size.height) / 2.0;

// Draw the image on it
[image drawInRect:projectRect];

// Get the image from the image context, retain it as our thumbnail
UIImage *small = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[self setThumbnail:small];

// Get the image as a PNG data
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(small);
[self setThumbnailData:data];

// Cleanup image context resources
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

}

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, i'm getting it conceptually!, I could really use some code if you'd post. Its very similar to what I want!

Comment: Hey, your help went a long way in my understanding.

Comment: I'd like to ask one more question, is it a good idea to store the thumbnail images in the documents and load it from there? considering there might be alot of images that will be loaded?

Comment: This answer looks like it straight from the Big Nerd Ranch iOS book.